# Chrome background-image doesn't refresh on click

Tags: css, google-chrome, refresh, background-image, reload

I am trying to create background-image switcher that changes background pattern of the body with a click on the button.

```
$(".ptn-ill").click(function(){
  $("body").addClass("pattern-ill");
});


.pattern-ill {
  background-color: rgb(43, 42, 47);
  background-image: url(../images/science.png);
  background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

It is working in Mozilla, but in Chrome it doesn't change image until I re-size the window. Is there any way to force chrome to refresh  `background-image` ?

Comment: sounds like a caching problem to me.

Comment: Try to clear browser cache and then try again.

Comment: can u make a jsfiddle ? so that i can check .

Comment: it is strange, in jsfiddle everything is working just fine http://jsfiddle.net/s64bfywL/4/

Answer (score 0):

I needed to apply background-image to wrapper instead of body tag. Also I needed to add bg color on every new background class, since chrome had issues with transparency too. Background-image property in chrome is behaving really poor when it comes to reloading on event...